# Home surveillance, TensorFlow (+ OpenCV)

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision

I am considering to implement a network of security cameras in my countryside property due to the recent intrusion of some burglars. To do so, I am trying to make the most out of the equipment I already have at home, such as:

- 6 IP night vision cameras
- Jetson TK1 as a processing unit,
  [https://www.nvidia.com/object/jetson-tk1-embedded-dev-kit.html][1]
- Raspberry Pi 2 model B (not needed, I guess)
- PoE Switch

I wanted to feed the video stream of each camera "into" TensorFlow+OpenCV (or other DeepLearning algorithms) to make sure I can recognise what's/who's in my garden, garage, etc. - basically it would be:

- Human detection & car detection

planning to use Telegram or other APIs provided by the instant messaging platform to be notified real-time.

Configuring Tensorflow on my ubuntu 16.04 LTS (workstation with GPU support) was not trivial at all nor it will be the process of recognising objects and people.

Do you have any recommendation on this little project?
Would it make sense using Docker to make the configuration smoother?

Comment: As for the actual detection, you could retrain something from the object detection API. There are some tutorials, but I found the stuff on the github to be the easiest to follow. https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break it down as follow:

1 - Decide between bounding box and semantic segmentation

2 - Select your pre-trained model after selecting your framework (Tensorflow in your case). You need to beat around Real Time vs Accuracy
2.1 - The best in my opinion would be MobilenetV2 based deeplab (segmentation) or NASNET (bounding box)

3 - Retrain it for transfer learning if Cars & Persons are not in your model, otherwise you dont need to

4 - Look for model optimization if required for Jetson TK1 (compression etc)

5 - Once successfully deployed and it starts looking for person and cars, develop your logic for how should it alert you. (e.g. absence of car for x consecutive frames or presence of person for x consecutive frames etc)

Happy Surveillaying!